# What is the correct BB spindle length for Kooka cranks?

Tags: crankset, bottom-bracket

Does anyone know the correct square taper bottom bracket spindle length for an early 90s Kooka triple mountain bike crankset?

Comment: Photos and/or details of models etc would help.  Pending that, are you able to get the info from the existing bottom bracket?

Comment: I will try to get photos tonight. It was mounted on a 107 BB which was obviously much too short. The inner chainring was removed so that it didn't rub on the chainstay.

Comment: If you already have the 107 BB, mount it loosely threaded into the frame and mount the drive side crank to it. Then mount your rear wheel with cassette. you should them be able to back out the Bottom Bracket out of the frame until you see the chainline that you desire. With a triple, I would not put the big ring out further from the frame than the small cog in the rear. Also make sure that the smallest ring comfortably clears the chainstay. This mock-up should help to find the right length.